# Prove that a functional on $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ is a distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I'm studying some functional analysis, and currently focusing on the theory of distributions. I came across the following exercise (ex. 21.2 in F. Treves, "Topological vector spaces, distributions and kernels") and I wanted to know if my approach to the solution is correct, as I'm still not familiar with these concepts. I would also appreciate any kind of alternative approach.

Let $\{x_j\}$ be a sequence of points in $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ (open) which does not have any accumulation point in $\Omega$. I need to prove that for any sequence of complex numbers $\{a_j\}$, the functional on $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ defined by
$$ \varphi \mapsto \sum_{j = 1}^\infty a_j D^\mathbb{j} \varphi(x_j)$$
is a distribution in $\Omega$ (that is, an element of the dual $\mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$).
The differential operator is defined as usual:
$$ D^\mathbb\alpha = \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \right)^{\alpha_1} \dotsb \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x_d} \right)^{\alpha_d}$$
for the multi-index $\mathbb{\alpha} = (\alpha_1, \dotsc, \alpha_d) \in \mathbb{N}^d$, and $\mathbb{j} = (j,\dotsc, j) \in \mathbb{N}^d$.
The set of test functions $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ is the set of functions $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathbb{C})$ whose support is a compact subset of $\Omega$.

**My solution:**
We know that the continuity of a map $\mathcal{D}(\Omega) \to Y$, where $Y$ is a locally convex topological vector space, is equivalent to sequential continuity in $0$. We thus consider a sequence $\{\varphi_n\}$ in $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ such that $\varphi_n \to 0$ (the topology on $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ is the canonical LF topology) and show that its image under the linear functional converges to $0$ in the locally convex TVS $\mathbb{C}$.

By a characterization of convergence in the space of test functions $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$, there exists a compact $K \subset \Omega$ such that $\text{supp}(\varphi_n) \subset \Omega$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $D^\alpha \varphi_n \to D^\alpha \varphi$ uniformly on $\Omega$ for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^d$.

Now, since the support of the $\varphi_n$ is compact and $\{x_j\}$ does not have any accumulation point, we can extract a finite number of points $\{x_{j_1}, \dotsc, x_{j_r}\} = K \cap \{x_1, x_2, \dotsc\}$ where $\varphi_n$ does not vanish for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
We have
$$ \left| \sum_{j = 1}^\infty a_j D^\mathbb{j} \varphi_n(x_j) \right| \leq
   \sum_{i = 1}^r \left| a_{j_i} D^\mathbb{j_i} \varphi_n(x_{j_i}) \right| \leq
   \max_{i=1, \dotsc, r} |a_{j_i}| \sum_{i = 1}^r \left| D^\mathbb{j_i} \varphi_n(x_{j_i}) \right|. $$
Let us denote $A = \max_{i = 1,\dotsc, r} |a_{j_i}|$.
Let $\epsilon > 0$. By the convergence $D^\mathbb{j_i} \varphi_n \to 0$ for every $i = 1, \dotsc, r$ (I think that pointwise convergence should even suffice here), we can find $n_i \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n \geq n_i$
$$ \left| D^\mathbb{j_i} \varphi_n(x_{j_i}) \right| < \frac{\epsilon}{r A}.$$
Letting $n_0 = \max_{i = 1,\dotsc,r} n_i$ we have, for $n \geq n_0$,
$$ \left| \sum_{j = 1}^\infty a_j D^\mathbb{j} \varphi_n(x_j) \right| < \epsilon, $$
so that the series converges to $0$ (in $\mathbb{C}$), concluding the proof.

Comment: The functional is basically a sum of derivatives of different orders of Dirac deltas located at different positions. The crucial point is that the positions are clearly distinct so that the maximum order on any compact set is finite.

Comment: Thanks! This gives me a much better intuition of why things work. Does that mean that I can also proceed by showing that for every compact $K$ the restriction of this functional to $D_K$ is continuous? I would use $(D^\alpha \delta_{x_i})(\varphi) = \delta_{x_i} (D^\alpha \varphi) = D^\alpha \varphi(x_i)$, and the fact that derivatives and finite sums of distributions are distributions (the sum would be finite for the same reason as above). Would this work?

Comment: Also, you say that the maximum order on any compact set is finite (and I guess this is simply because the sum being finite, it involves a finite number of derivatives, so that there is a maximum order between them). But does this distribution have infinite order "globally" (in $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$) ?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your first question (about showing that the restriction to $D_K$ is continuous). What are the practical differences to what you did above?

Comment: Yes, this distribution has an infinite global order (usually just called "order").

Comment: @md2perpe Above I proving continuity by showing sequential continuity at $0$ (I take a sequence $(\varphi_n) \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega)$, I find a compact $K$ which contains it, and show that the sequence of the images converges to 0), here I am proving continuity by showing that the restriction of the functional to every compact $K$ is continuous (another criterion for convergence for maps $\mathcal{D}(\Omega) \to Y$, where $Y$ is a LCTVS), without defining any sequence. But I get that the reason why these two appraoches work is obviously the same (the finiteness of the sum on every compact)